# What's the correct way of adding code after the start of the body tag?

Tags: javascript, joomla-3.6, facebook

So, I've just recently added the Facebook Javascript SDK to my site to be able to enable a "like" button to my pages.

Facebook recommends adding this right after the opening `<body>` tag. The only I could find to do this was to modify the `index.php` file of my template.

The danger here is that my code will be wiped if the template is updated. This is not a huge deal, but would make future-proofing the site a lot easier to do this correctly.

So, what's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complementing the answer from @veritas399, you could also use a third party extension such as [EasyScript](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/easyscript) or similar to insert the code into your web page without worrying about future template or other updates overwriting your code.

Facebook may recommend adding this right after the opening `<body>` tag but [this may not be the best advice from a performance point of view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/196718/1983389) and is likely not essential.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to edit the template's `index.php` file, then I'd suggest that you use a plugin and utilise `JApplication` to get and set the body.

You can then use the following in your plugin:

```
public function onAfterRender()
{
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();

    if ($app->isSite())
    {
        $buffer = $app->getBody();

        $insert = '<div>YOUR HTML CODE TO INSERT</div>';

        $buffer = preg_replace('/<body[^>]+>\K/i', $insert, $buffer);

        // Use the replaced HTML body.
        $app->setBody($buffer);
    }
}
```

The regular expression finds the opening  `body` tag and any attributes that you may have inside it, then "forgets the matched string" with the `\K` metachatacter so that the `$insert` text is immediately added after the opening body tag (no text will be removed).

Answer (score 1):

Is your template based on one of the popular frameworks? (Gantry 5 by RocketTheme, Warp by YooTheme, T3 by JoomlaArt, etc.)
If so, that framework provider should have documented how and where to make changes that will survive upgrades. For example, one can add [custom code to Gantry 5 templates](http://docs.gantry.org/gantry5/configure/page-settings) in the head and body tags on the admin panel.

Comment: I'm not sure. It's Theme 1498 by template monster, but thanks I will look into their documentation.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @Neil Robertson's answer - there are tons of plugins/extensions that implement **Facebook Like/Share** and other **Social Sites Integrations** - which might be a better alternative for you, since your actual requirement is to simply add **FB Like Buttons**.

Have a look at JED:

- [**JED Social Web**](https://extensions.joomla.org/category/social-web)
- [**JED Social Sharing**](https://extensions.joomla.org/category/social-web/social-share)

Also, some templates provide such features and all you have to do is to add your own FB App ID - so make sure you have search in your template about this possibility.

Comment: I saw the plugins, and I've considered looking under the hood to see how they add the SDK. I chose not to go with a plugin because most seemed to have more functionality than I needed, and seemed like overkill to add a few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

The template usually would be the place to do that. You could add the code to a separate facebook.php file in yout template directory and the add that to the index.php file through a php include:

```
<body>
<?php include('facebook.php'); ?>
...
```

Comment: I had just read that template updates would overwrite anything in the index.php; don't know how often or likely that is

Answer (score 0):

Or, alternately, instead of installing a bunch of stuff, you could put it where you want it and then right click and select all and copy and paste it into a wordpad file, save it and name it SITE-index-php and then just copy that file back in any time there's an update. Takes like 1 minute and nothing else to install or mess around with.

Comment: This doesn't seem like professional-grade advice.  Using this technique will require the developer to do more work in the long run and there is the risk of forgetting to overwrite the content on each upgrade.

Comment: You're probably right. I just try to minimize installing extensions thinking the more there are the more vulnerable your site becomes.