# How to get rendered full page before returning to the browser?

Tags: articles, content

Is there any way to get full rendered page before returning to the browser?
I want to get full page (from `<html>` to `</html>`), replace some pseudo variables and retrun to user changed verstion. 
I can do this using index.php 
but I looks ugly.

Maybe there is a callback like "on after page rendered"?

Comment: Worth reading over... https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/323/12352 , https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/20880/12352 , https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/18904/12352

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To edit entire HTML output directly, create a system plugin with `onAfterRender` event. Use application's `getBody()` method to get the content and `setBody()` to save the modified content.

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

plgSystemExample
{
    protected $app;

    public function onAfterRender()
    {
        if ($this->app->getDocument()->type !== 'html')
        {
            return;
        }

        $body = $this->app->getBody();

        //do modifications to $body here

        $this->app->setBody($body);
    }
}
```

But if the content you want to replace is only inside content items (e.g. shortcodes in articles), create a content plugin with `onContentPrepare` event and only modify the article text.